# Produce a scatter plot but using three variables

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

This is a rather strange plot that I need to produce and was hoping somebody could help me with this.

My data is this:

```
a<-c(1760,650,1210,1670,1150,1720,1900,2010,1500,1720,1430,2090,1840)
b<-c(992,1072,1522,521,851,583,868,591,794,621,767,951,740)
min_b<-c(963,1036,1405,502,834,559,806,558,741,597,725,914,725)
max_b<-c(1042,1104,1662,543,887,619,898,635,841,646,838,1018,757)
year<-c(1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)
data<-data.frame(a,b,min_b,max_b,year)
```

The first plot I produce is `a vs b` with `min` and `max` of `b` shown on the plot using the following command:

```
plot(data$a, data$b)
arrows(data$a, data$min_b, data$a, data$max_b,col="black",lty=1, code=3, angle=90, length=0.1)
```

Is there any way this scatter plot could be produced in a chronological order (i.e. according to year).
I would be thankful for any help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You say you want 1998 to appear "first" - like an animation? Or you want these in separate plots?

Comment: No. For example if you were to run the above script, you will see that `a vs b` of 2009 appears at the end of x-axis and 1999 appears at beginning of x-axis. What I want to do is `a vs b` of `1998` first (on x axis), then `a vs b` of `1999` and so on with `a vs b` of 2010 appearing in the end of x-axix. Just one plot and no animation. Hope this is slightly more clear

Comment: Are you after effectively an a vs b chart for every year in chronological order so that there's only ever one point on the axis?

Comment: This still isn't very clear or at least doesn't make much sense. What is it that you're really trying to show here?

Comment: Well I got the answer. If you could look at the answer below, this is what I was looking for. I could not post a pic of an example plot because I did not have require reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's ok not to use base graphics , this ggplot2 version using facetting may serve you well
[image: facetted ggplot]

The code for this is:

```
library(ggplot2)
# map your data to relevant axis values
ggplot(data,aes(x=a,y=b,ymin=min_b, ymax=max_b))+
# Plot you points (you can customise this)
  geom_point()+
# Plot your error bars (using ymin and ymax
  geom_errorbar()+
# split your chart by year
  facet_wrap(~year)
```

### Forcing onto one row

The code becomes:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=a,y=b,ymin=min_b, ymax=max_b))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_errorbar()+
  facet_wrap(~year,ncol = length(year))
```

The chart produced is:
[image: Single row chronology]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. But I need this in just one plot rather than in multiple plots like this.

Comment: How big will you be able to display the chart? If you have a lot of years but want to be able to keep a reasonable level of scale on your x axis it would have to be quite big. Are there other options we could do like encoding b as a colour on the error bar?

Comment: well the data which I gave is the actual data. So i have only 13 years.

Comment: Updated my answer to put it all in a single row - there are tweaks that could be done to the x axis to make it more readable, or the values could be removed entirely if relative position is more important than absolute position

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for this. If you have time, could you tell me how can I change the symbol of first 6 years (a triangle may be) and how to do away with the clumsy x-axis?

Comment: You can encode values to the shape of the points in ggplot. The laziest way of doing this would be to do change the `geom_point()` line to `geom_point(aes(shape=year<=2003))`. The [ggplot2 documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) is really good - for lots of the aethestic tweaking, I really recommend it.